# Automatically generate windows forms

Tags: c#, xml, windows, winforms

We have a C# Windows application which have 100+ forms. Those forms frequently need to be changed (add new controls). New controls can be Combo, Text Box or a Check Box only.

Can we have a mechanism where we can keep those forms (structure) as XML files (or in any other format) and load as a windows form when loading. So 'NO' development (re-building) is needed.

Please provide me example how we can achieve this

Note : Data Loading to those new controls and saving is not an issue. Since that is already handled globally.

Comment: If your forms are the same, you can just design a form and create multi instances of that form. using XML can help you store everything and so storing some form information is of course OK.

Comment: "Yes, you can". If this does not help you, you may want to ask a question appropriate to this site. If in doubt, read the section labeled "help" on the upper right.

Comment: @KingKing They are not same.

Comment: @nvoigt If you know the answer please post it. This site is to help others than boasting about yourself.

Comment: Without any indication of what you already *can* do, it's hard to answer this. There is no single-line magic solution. You could write a whole book about it. That's why the help site states you should add what you already tried. Can you create a Form? Can you dynamically create a Form? Can you load XML? Can you parse dynamic XML? Can you put both together?

Comment: Not sure I understand the requirement.  You wish to add extra components to existing forms, connecting them up to the existing event-handler code?